# select count(*) in subquery - cakephp 3.6

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have tried to write this query in cakephp 3.6:

```
SELECT `Group`.`id`, `Group`.`name`, `Group`.`created`, `Group`.`modified`, (SELECT count(*)
                            FROM `positions` where Group.id = positions.group_id) AS "count" FROM `groups` AS `Group`
```

i can use raw query to get the result, but how can use ORM\Query to implement this?

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Show some effort and read at least the manual. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html

Comment: I have tried but i can't, so i need the help from community, pls understand this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Something likes this.

```
$query = $this->Groups->find();
$query->select([
        'Groups.id',
        'Groups.name', 
        'Groups.created', 
        'Groups.modified',
        'count' => $query->func()->count('Positions.id')
    ])->leftJoinWith('Positions')
      ->group('Groups.id');
```

Comment: Thank you but do we need create association between Groups and Positions? I run the query and it show error.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the solution:

```
$position = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Positions');
        $q = $position->find();
        $q->select([$q->func()->count('*')])
                    ->where(['Positions.group_id = Groups.id']);
        $query = $this->Groups->find()
         ->select(['id',  'name', 'created', 'modified' , 'count' => $q]);
```

When checking the log i get:

```
SELECT Groups.id AS `Groups__id`, Groups.name AS `Groups__name`, Groups.created AS `Groups__created`, Groups.modified AS `Groups__modified`, (SELECT (COUNT(*)) FROM positions Positions WHERE Positions.group_id = Groups.id) AS `count` FROM groups Groups
```